# LLVM JIT fabsf resolve error when using powf

Tags: c++, c++11, llvm

I was experimenting with LLVMs JIT capabilities and while calling `powf` I observed that while calling `powf` works if I simply add a declaration for it

```
declare float @powf(float, float))
```

and call it with two variables

```
%4 = call float @powf(float %3, float %2)
```

However when I do the same with a constant exponent of `0.5`

```
%4 = call float @powf(float %3, float 5.000000e-01)
```

It fails with the following error:

> LLVM ERROR: Program used external function 'fabsf' which could not be resolved!

The `powf` call is replaced by the following by the optimization passes, so I know where the `fabsf` comes from:

```
%sqrtf = tail call float @sqrtf(float %3) #1
%fabsf = tail call float @fabsf(float %sqrtf) #1
%4 = fcmp oeq float %3, 0xFFF0000000000000
%5 = select i1 %4, float 0x7FF0000000000000, float %fabsf
```

I tried registering `fabsf` externally (but apparently incorrectly), but that didn't work:

```
auto float_type = llvm::Type::getFloatTy(context);
std::vector<llvm::Type *> unary_arg_types(1, float_type);
auto unary_op_type = llvm::FunctionType::get(float_type, unary_arg_types, false);
auto fabsf_llvm = llvm::Function::Create(unary_op_type, llvm::Function::ExternalLinkage, "fabsf", module);
ee->addGlobalMapping(fabsf_llvm, reinterpret_cast<void *>(&::fabsf));
```

I am using the MCJIT ExecutionEngine and running on Windows 7 with LLVM and my test program compiled with MinGW.

**Question 1:** How do I register `fabsf` so that the error does not occur?

**Question 2:** Why is the `fabsf` necessary here?

**EDIT:** It appears I have stumbled onto a (known) MCJIT Bug: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=20656

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is a known bug in MCJIT.

I stumbled upon a solution to this on the LLVMDev mailing list. 
You can use `llvm::sys::DynamicLibrary::AddSymbol()`located in the `llvm/Support/DynamicLibrary.h` header to register you missing symbols. This is the answer to your **Question 1**.

For **Question 2**: (disclaimer: I am not a floating point specialist and don't know if anything is true what I write here)

Since `powf` is transformed to `sqrtf` you will get a QNaN (quiet NaN) when the result of `sqrtf` is undefined because a negative argument is supplied. In ISO 754 a `QNaN` is represented as `0xFFF0000000000000` or `0x7FF0000000000000` (the sign does not matter for `QNaN` in ISO 754) .

In C++ we have the following definition for [`pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow):

> pow(base, exp) returns NaN and raises FE_INVALID if base is finite and
>   negative and exp is finite and non-integer.
>
> ...
>
> pow(±0, exp), where exp is positive non-integer or a positive even
>   integer, returns +0

Note that it will return a positive `0` every time.

However for [`sqrt`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt):

> If the argument is +∞ or ±0, it is returned, unmodified.

To finally answer your question: `fabsf` in your case is necessary to get rid of the sign that `sqrt` preservers while `pow` throws it away.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot about the signed 0 passing through `sqrt` unmodified. Could you elaborate on your answer to Q1?

Comment: Forget about that, I thought I'd have to create a DynamicLibrary instance, but it's a simple static function. Now the only question is... why isn't the fabsf lowered to an intrinsic/the FABS instruction...